# Angular2: Having trouble in using an EventEmitter

Tags: typescript, event-handling, angular, master-detail

I have a child component which is a list of several devices, and its parent component which displays the details of the selected device. I would like to handle an EventEmitter in order to be able to change my selected device when needed, but I get a

```
Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component 'ListOfDevicesComponent'
```

The whole log in the console says:

```
EXCEPTION: Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component 'ListOfDevicesComponent'
angular2.dev.js:23083 EXCEPTION: Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component 'ListOfDevicesComponent'BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23083BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ angular2.dev.js:23094ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1185(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12591NgZone._notifyOnError @ angular2.dev.js:13515collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @ angular2.dev.js:13419Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1247(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13438zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch @ angular2-polyfills.js:468lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback @ angular2-polyfills.js:480lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish @ angular2-polyfills.js:451(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:123microtask @ angular2.dev.js:13470Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13438zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2-polyfills.js:262
angular2.dev.js:23083 STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23083ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1187(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12591NgZone._notifyOnError @ angular2.dev.js:13515collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @ angular2.dev.js:13419Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1247(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13438zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch @ angular2-polyfills.js:468lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback @ angular2-polyfills.js:480lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish @ angular2-polyfills.js:451(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:123microtask @ angular2.dev.js:13470Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13438zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2-polyfills.js:262
angular2.dev.js:23083 Error: Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component 'ListOfDevicesComponent'
    at new BaseException (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:7351:21)
    at RuntimeMetadataResolver.getViewDirectivesMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:22367:17)
    at TemplateCompiler._compileNestedComponentRuntime (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:24329:63)
    at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:24314:26
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:24313:37
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1243:24)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:13438:32)
    at zoneBoundFn (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1220:26)
    at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:468:17)

-----async gap-----
Error
    at _getStacktraceWithUncaughtError (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:2236:29)
    at Zone.fork (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:2285:47)
    at Zone.bind (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1218:53)
    at bindArguments (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1401:36)
    at lib$es6$promise$promise$$Promise.obj.(anonymous function) [as then] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1413:46)
    at TemplateCompiler._compileComponentRuntime (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:24307:14)
    at TemplateCompiler._compileNestedComponentRuntime (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:24333:12)
    at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:24314:26
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:24313:37
```

I have commented some of my code lines in order to understand where the problem was coming from, and it seems that it is coming from that line in my child component:

```
private selectDevice: EventEmitter<Device> = new EventEmitter();
```

When I delete this line, no more error message!

I give you all the parts of my code which could be related to my problem if you want to take a look.

This is a part of my child component (ListOfDevicesComponent):

```
@Component({
    // Other properties...
    inputs: ['selectedDevice'],
    outputs: ['selectDevice'],
    directives: [
    DeviceOverviewComponent,
    ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class ListOfDevicesComponent {
    private devices = this._devicesServices.getDevices();
    private selectedDevice: Device;
    private selectDevice: EventEmitter<Device> = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(private _devicesServices: DevicesServices) {}

    onSelect(device: Device) {
        this.selectDevice.next(device);
    }
}
```

and a part of its template:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="#device of devices" [class.active]="device === selectedDevice" (click)="onSelect(device)">
        <device-overview [currentDevice]="device" ></device-overview>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This is a part of my parent component (DeviceDetailsComponent):

```
@Component({
    // Other properties...
    directives: [
        ListOfDevicesComponent,
        ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class DeviceDetailsComponent {
    private devices = this._devicesServices.getDevices();
    private selectedDevice: Device;

    constructor(private _devicesServices: DevicesServices) {}

    handleSelectDevice(device) {
        this.selectedDevice = device;
    }

}
```

in which I have integrated its child this way:

```
<list-of-devices [selectedDevice]="device" (selectDevice)="handleSelectDevice($event)"></list-of-devices>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like here is the `device-overview` component missing in the `directives:` parameter

```
@Component({
    // Other properties...
    inputs: ['selectedDevice'],
    outputs: ['selectDevice'],
    directives: [DeviceOverview], // <==
})

export class ListOfDevicesComponent {
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but actually I've already included the `directives:` parameter, it was just hidden in `// Other properties...`. I've just added it in my original post so that no one else misunderstands it. I still have the same problem though.

Comment: This was just a guess. Your question doesn't provide enough information to figure out what the problem could be.

Comment: I'm sure I can see what details I can add to be more precise. Maybe the whole log in the console of my browser could help you to help me... I'm adding it to my post right now!

Comment: Log doesn't really help.

Comment: I have tried to make a plunker if it can helps, there it is: https://plnkr.co/edit/n89vclvBOG9kVOc0VvjC?p=preview I'm not sure to have done all that it takes, this is my first plunker. So don't hesitate to tell me if I should add something. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `boot.ts` had a missing import `import {AppComponent} from "./main";` otherwise it looks fine but doesn't load `AppComponent` but also doesn't produce an error. I don't have experience myself with Router and expecially Router in Plunker.

Comment: OK... I have modified my plunker with less rooting since this is not the point here: https://plnkr.co/edit/HOYwXRJOBCGnjZ1dbtjr?p=preview. And actually, it works. But, when I copy and paste the code, I mean, literraly copy and paste all the code, component by component (except the paths of the imports which are not the same), it throws me `EXCEPTION: Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component 'ListOfDevicesComponent'` 3 times in the browser console log. Do you have any idea from where this could come from?

Comment: This has to be `DeviceOverviewComponent`, right? Do you have `class DeviceOverviewComponent` in an external file or in the same file as `ListOfDevicesComponent`?

Comment: I've found what was going wrong: I used single or double quotes for my imports, and SystemJS doesn't like that. Unrelated to that specific problem after all... Anyway, thanks a lot for your help Gunter!